# Swift Array of Closures - Lookup an element

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, closures

```
let tabClosures = [
"Adicionar": {(a:Float, b:Float)-> Float in var varaux = a + b; return varaux;},     "Subtrair":{(a:Float, b:Float)-> Float in var varaux = a - b; return varaux;},     "Multiplicar": {$0 * $1},     
"FarToCelsius": { (a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in var varaux = (a * 9 / 5 + 32); return varaux;},     
"CelsiusToFar": { (a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in var varaux = (a - 32)*5/9; return varaux;},     
"KelvinToCelsius": { (a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in var varaux = (a - 273.15); return varaux;},     
"CelsiusToKelvin": { (a:Float, b:Float) -> Float in var varaux = (a + 273.15); return varaux;} ]  
let val1:Float = 120.1 
let val2:Float = 10.1  
for(x, y) in tabClosures{     
if( x == "FarToCelsius"){         
print("\(x): \(y(val1, val2))")}     
else     if( x == "CelsiusToFar"){         
print("\(x): \(y(val1, val2))")}}
```

How can I pick-up an element of thhis array without the For cycle. I want, for instance with a string search an element. 
Foor example I have a string that is "FarToCelsius" and I want to execute "FarToCelsius" closure element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Dictionary you can do just that:

```
if let fn = tabClosures["FarToCelsius"] {
    let res = fn(2.2, 3.0)
    print("\(res)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not realise that was a dictionary. I am starting to study Swift